# Mount/unmount vue components depend on screen size (tailwind/vue)

Tags: css, vuejs2, components, lifecycle

For different screen sizes i need two different components.
I try to decide which component to load with a simple hidden flag

```
<div>
  <ComponentA class="hidden sm:flex" />
  <ComponentB class="sm:hidden" />
</div>
```

The problem here is, that i have a mounted and unmounted function in my ComponentA class. This functions seems to be executed anyways the ComponentA is hidden or not.

```
  mounted() {
this.$store.commit('doSomething')
 },
 destroyed() {
 this.$store.commit('removeSomething')
},
```

When on small screensize, i want ComponentB to be in the state as if ComponentB has been destroyed/never been mounted. Or something to prevent ComponentA from mountig if im on small screen size.

Is there anyway to archive this?

Comment: You can try <component :is="[name of the component] /> and activated/deactivated events, see https://vegibit.com/vuejs-dynamic-components/

Comment: Hi, this could be work. What i need to do is now, to listen for screen size changes and switch between componentA and componentB dynamically with the dynamic components concept. You have any idea how to do this?

Comment: Okey i got it work, simply add a window eventlistener  into created hook. thank you! :)